# jQuery clone and append function isn't working as expected in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-directive

in my app I'm trying I'm building a shopping cart. You can see the app in this codepen: http://codepen.io/summerfreeze/pen/VjqJYW.  It's almost working, but I'm struggling with the last part. I want the "ADD ORDER LINE" button to add another order lines under the existing one. I'm trying to do this using jQuery:

```
  myApp.directive('myDirective', function($scope) {
    $scope.addline = function() {
      $(".orderline").clone().appendTo('.main');
    };
    return addline();
  });
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I would be grateful if someone would look at the code and tell me what mistake did I make.

Comment: This contains several syntax errors. Is it your full code?

Comment: Don't mix jQuery with AngularJS. I suggest you have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat.

Comment: I agree with @Wawy for starters. Secondly, check what you're returning. `addline` is undefined...

Comment: I'm new to Angular and I have no idea how to do this without jQuery. I tried to code something, but it didn't work either

Comment: $SteamDev - how is addline undefined? it's a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you were using a directive. I removed that from your code and it works. You still have other errors, but I'm guessing you can attend to those.
Here's the link to the modified version

[new codepen version](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWBoqV)

```
   $scope.addline = function(){
    $(".orderline").clone().appendTo('.main');
  };
```

As the others suggested, in order to follow clean code standards, please refrain from using jQuery code in AngularJS, in time it will lead to problems.

Comment: I will surely learn to do this with Angular soon, thank you. Your code does work, but please click few times and see how many divs it adds. It multiplies. How to avoid that?

Comment: use the ".first()" function from jquery
`$(".orderline").first().clone().appendTo('.main');`

Comment: the cloned input lements don't work as the original one (no autocomplete etc)

Comment: Yes, that's why you need to rethink the approach in an Angular way, cloned elements are not really dynamic. Do more Angular exercises/examples until you understand the basics and then you can apply them in your project.

Comment: http://codepen.io/summerfreeze/pen/VjqJYW trying to do that in Angular, bit i'm lost

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you shouldn't be appending to `#main`, but to `#main div[0]`